# ErrorException in CrudTrait.php Undefined offset: 0 Backpack for Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

i want create dynamic combobox from database, but i have an error with this message :

ErrorException in CrudTrait.php line 32: Undefined offset: 0 (View: /home/vagrant/Code/hrd/resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/select2.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/hrd/resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/select2.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/hrd/resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/select2.blade.php)

This is my DistrictCrudController.php :

```
<?php



namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

use App\Http\Requests\DistrictRequest as StoreRequest;

use App\Http\Requests\DistrictRequest as UpdateRequest;

class DistrictCrudController extends CrudController {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->crud->setModel("App\Models\District");
        $this->crud->setRoute("admin/district");
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('district', 'districts');
        $this->crud->setFromDb();

        $this->crud->addField([  
                               'label' => "City",
                               'type' => 'select2',// the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                               'name' => 'city_id', // the db column for the foreign key
                               'entity' => 'cities', //tabel entity
                               'attribute' => 'id', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
                               'model' => "App\Models\City" // foreign key model
                            ]);                   
    }

    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        return parent::storeCrud();
    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        return parent::updateCrud();
    }
}
```

The code is run well if i remove :

```
$this->crud->addField([  
                               'label' => "City",
                               'type' => 'select2',// the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                               'name' => 'city_id', // the db column for the foreign key
                               'entity' => 'cities', //tabel entity
                               'attribute' => 'id', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
                               'model' => "App\Models\City" // foreign key model
                            ]);
```

I use Backpack for Laravel 5.2

Comment: Hi corfied. To debug this, could you please go to CrudTrait.php:32 and copy-paste the code there? Also, are you sure you've got the "cities" relationship on your District model? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will solve, but i can only see two issues that might be causing that.

You don't have cities relationship defined or you could try using:

```
public function setUp()
    {
$this->crud->setModel("App\Models\District");
        $this->crud->setRoute("admin/district");
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('district', 'districts');
        $this->crud->setFromDb();
...
...
```

don't use parent::__construct().

Give it a try and post your results if not solved.